# Django built-in User Model implementation

Tags: django, authentication, django-models

I'm trying to use the built in User model provided by Django in my app, but I'm not sure how to implement it (i.e., what does my models.py file actually look like?) I'm starting off by building a simple login form with the Django auth system.

I'm seeing multiple examples on the web where they import User but never define anything. Like so

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

#nothing similar to defining User (i.e. 'class User: #fields')
```

What I'm assuming is by importing User, you don't have to define anything, since it's already been defined, but when I go to run "python manage.py sql 'name'" nothing is executed.

Comment: You actually need to spend sometime reading the detailed documentation that Django offers: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: Thanks for the resource! I didn't think of looking at that page yet because I assumed I wouldn't be customizing anything and just using the default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a models file for the user, because Django already supplies one. You just need to ensure that `django.contrib.user` is in INSTALLED_APPS.

The only reason you would need to import User into another models file is if you wanted to add a ForeignKey from one of your own models to the User model. In all likelihood, you *do* want to do that eventually; but you don't need to just in order to get the user models created.

Comment: After doing some more reading I came to the same conclusion. Thanks for the tip, really helped clear my mind